# Border around main content and sidebar

Tags: css, border

I can't seem to get the border on the following page (and website) to behave itself. [http://alisonkeane.com.au/test/

For some reason the border only goes the length of the content of the sidebar, so this is a problem when the main content is longer.

I've had to place widgets with blank lines in the sidebards to correct this but that's not a solution as the website owner needs to constantly change the content.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Kind regards,

Jacqui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is use "overflow: hidden" for your #wrapper class. This will solve the problem.

CSS File Path:
http://alisonkeane.com.au/wp-content/themes/zeecorporate/style.css?ver=4.0

Class: #Wrapper

Add Property: overflow: hidden;

Comment: Excellent thanks Kiran.  Seems to fix the border problem perfectly.  Is there anyway that I can make the sidebar background match the length down to the bottom border?

Comment: You can follow flex box approach to achieve this. Here is the link - http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Gawd.  I get the concept of the flexbox but wouldn't have enough knowledge with CSS to implement it.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hi Kiran
Appreciate your help yesterday.  Any other suggestions apart from the flex box approach?